# Converting openoffice.org text document to spreadsheet

Tags: openoffice.org

Any ideas for how to convert an openoffice.org text document
into spreadsheet format, programatically, if possible?

Comment: Can you show an example of an input and output document? Programmatically on what platform?

Comment: what platform? what language? You need some more tags

Comment: What's wrong with copy and paste?  Why didn't that work?

Comment: S.Lott: Copy&paste does NOT work. When I copy an area in the text document, open calc, and try to paste there , a new text document is opened ... and then pasted.                                                                    Pekka: Programatically on linux ubuntu (Maverick).  The document was originally a calc document, but somebody else converted it before doing some small changes.                                                                                                --- language for programmatic solution could be shell script, python, or something else (but first two preferred).

Comment: Please **update** your question with these additional details.  Do not comment on your own question.  **Update** your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record: This is what I finally did: With synaptic I installed
the excellent little program     odt2txt.
With that I extracted the text content, edited it manually a little in emacs, 
gave it extension  .csv   and then it imported nice in openoffice.org calc.